# Foreground WorkManager Не заканчивает рвботу

Tags: android, kotlin, service, android-service

Использую workManager для отслеживания передвижения и вести счет таймера, что бы workManager не приостанавливался при блокировке экрана решил выводить все через setForegroundAsync, но когда мне больше не нужен WorkManager процесс не убивается прямым вызовом

```
   @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun startTrackLocation(context: Context) {
        val locationWorker =
            OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<TrackLocationWorker>()
                .addTag(LOCATION_WORK_TAG)
                .build()

        WorkManager
            .getInstance(context)
            .enqueueUniqueWork(
                LOCATION_WORK_TAG,
                ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE,
                locationWorker
            )
    }

    fun stopTrackLocation(context: Context) {
        Log.e(TAG,"cancel workManager")
        repository.stopForeground()
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).cancelAllWorkByTag(LOCATION_WORK_TAG)
        updateState()
    }
```

Вызов и убийство WorkManager

```
@HiltWorker
class TrackLocationWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted private val context: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
    private val repository: RunRepository
) : Worker(context, workerParams) {

    private var channelIdFin: String? = null

    private lateinit var mFuture: SettableFuture<Result>
    private val timer: Timer by lazy { Timer() }
    val service: NotificationManager by lazy {
        context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    }

    private val fusedLocationProvider: FusedLocationProviderClient by lazy {
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
    }

        private val callback = object : LocationCallback(){
            override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
                locationResult.locations ?: return
                repository.emitLocationFlow(locationResult.lastLocation)
            }
        }

        private fun stopWork(){
            //timer.stopTimer()
            onStopped()
            //WorkManager.getInstance(context).createCancelPendingIntent(id)
        }

        override fun onStopped() {
            Log.e(TAG,"onStopped")
            fusedLocationProvider.removeLocationUpdates(callback)
            timer.stopTimer()
            super.onStopped()
        }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        try {
            repository.bindForeground { isStart ->
                if (isStart) {
                    timer.startTimer {
                        repository.emitTimer(it)
                        setForegroundAsync(getForegroundInfo(it))
                    }
                    setForegroundAsync(getForegroundInfo(0L))
                } else {
                    stopWork()
                }
            }

            val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
                interval = 5000L
                fastestInterval = 2000L
                priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
            }

            fusedLocationProvider.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, callback, Looper.getMainLooper())

            return Result.success()
        } catch (e: Throwable){
            return Result.failure()
        }
    }

    private fun getForegroundInfo(milliSeconds: Long): ForegroundInfo {
            if (channelIdFin == null) {
                channelIdFin =
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        createNotificationChannel(service)
                    } else {
                        ""
                    }
            }

            val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelIdFin!!)
            val notification = notificationBuilder
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.planet)
                .setContentTitle(milliSeconds.returnTimeWithoutMilliSecondsFromMilliseconds())
                .setSubText(RUN)
                .build()

            //service.notify(101,notification)

            return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                ForegroundInfo(102, notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION)
            } else {
                ForegroundInfo(102, notification)
            }
        }

        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        private fun createNotificationChannel(service: NotificationManager): String{
            NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH).also {
                it.lightColor = context.getColor(R.color.purple_700)
                it.importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
                service.createNotificationChannel(it)
            }
            return channelId
        }
```

Сам WorkManager

```
//workManager
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime-ktx:1.0.1"
```

Версия WorkManager (Возможно проблема в ней, но заметил когда ставишь другую Hilt не хочет ее находить, хотя все правила соблюденыы)

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App: Application(), Configuration.Provider {

    @Inject
    lateinit var workerFactory: RunWorkerFactory

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
        Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()
}

  <provider
            android:name="androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.workmanager-init"
            tools:node="remove" />

class RunWorkerFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: RunRepository
): WorkerFactory() {

    override fun createWorker(
        appContext: Context,
        workerClassName: String,
        workerParameters: WorkerParameters
    ): ListenableWorker {
        return TrackLocationWorker(appContext,
            workerParameters,
            repository
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: А воркер возвращает результат работы? Или продолжает работать в цикле? А то не совсем понял некоторые вызовы. Просто, если он зависает в работе, то он естественно не завершится. Чтобы это произошло, воркер должен проверить свое состояние `isStopped()`. А так же, чем вам не нравится котлиновский воокер? `CoroutineWorker`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@HiltWorker
class TrackLocationWorker @AssistedInject constructor(
    @Assisted private val context: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters,
    private val repository: RunRepository
) : ListenableWorker (context, workerParams) {

    private var channelIdFin: String? = null

    private lateinit var mFuture: SettableFuture<Result>
    private val timer: Timer by lazy { Timer() }

    val notificationManager: NotificationManager by lazy {
        context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    }

    private val fusedLocationProvider: FusedLocationProviderClient by lazy {
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
    }

    private val callback = object : LocationCallback(){
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            locationResult.locations ?: return
            repository.emitLocationFlow(locationResult.lastLocation)
        }
    }


    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    private fun stopWork(){
        Log.e(TAG,"stopWork")
        fusedLocationProvider.removeLocationUpdates(callback)
        timer.stopTimer()
        mFuture.set(Result.success())
    }

    private fun getForegroundInfo(): ForegroundInfo {
        if (channelIdFin == null) {
            channelIdFin =
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    createNotificationChannel(notificationManager)
                } else {
                    ""
                }
        }

        val intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0,
            Intent(context, RunActivity::class.java).putExtra(Constant.FROM_WORKMANAGER,true),
            0
        )

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelIdFin!!)
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.planet)
            .setContentTitle("00:00")
            .setSubText(RUN)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(intent)

        val foregroundInfo = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ForegroundInfo(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build(), FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION)
        } else {
            ForegroundInfo(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build())
        }

        timer.startTimer {
            repository.emitTimer(it)
            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(it.returnTimeWithoutMilliSecondsFromMilliseconds())
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build())
        }


        return foregroundInfo
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createNotificationChannel(service: NotificationManager): String{
        NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH).also {
            it.lightColor = context.getColor(R.color.purple_700)
            it.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
            service.createNotificationChannel(it)
        }
        return channelId
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission", "RestrictedApi")
    override fun startWork(): ListenableFuture<Result> {
        mFuture = SettableFuture.create()
        try {
            repository.bindForeground { isStart ->
                if (isStart) {
                    setForegroundAsync(getForegroundInfo())
                } else {
                    stopWork()
                }
            }

            val locationRequest = LocationRequest.create().apply {
                interval = 5000L
                fastestInterval = 2000L
                priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
            }

            fusedLocationProvider.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, callback, Looper.getMainLooper())

            //  mFuture.set(Result.success())
        } catch (e: Throwable){
            mFuture.set(Result.failure())
        }
        return mFuture
    }

    override fun onStopped() {
        Log.e(TAG,"onStooped")
        super.onStopped()
    }
}
```

Переписав свой Worker поменяв его на ListenableWorker и вызывав mFuture.set(Result.success()) по окнчанию работы я добился поведение которое мне нужно